# Can you put multiple tracking codes in one script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, facebook-pixel

Im wondering if it makes a difference if I put all javascript tracking codes in one `<script>` or do I have to put it in different `<script>` tags?

For example:

**Option 1:**

```
<script>
    /* Google Analytics tracking code*/

    /* Intercom chat tracking code */

    /* Facebook Pixel tracking code */
</script>
```

OR

**Option 2:**

```
<script>
    /* Google Analytics tracking code*/
</script>

<script>
    /* Intercom chat tracking code */
</script>

<script>
    /* Facebook Pixel tracking code */
</script>
```

Does it matter at all? thanks

Comment: Of course. Provided there’s no conflicting named variables or functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't matter. All `script` tags (either inline or with `src`) are effectively joined together in order into one long script.

Answer (score 0):

depends how you do it, if the scripts are in files, it is better to put everything in a single file because you only have to load only once and not separately. Example:
it's better:

```
<script src='/GoogleIntercomFacebook.js'></script>
```

to be this:

```
<script src="Google.js"></script>
<script src="Intercom.js"></script>
<script src="Facebook.js"></script>
```